# Error receiving data: Connection reset by peer in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, gnome, 17.10

I tried to connect to my college network using Ubuntu 17.10 Gnome. After entering the password, the dialog box containing the error "Error receiving data: Connection reset by peer" shows up. And then WiFi disconnects and never connects again to that specific network.